# Jenkins BUILD_LOG_REGEX ( emailext plugin ) does not match across multiple lines ( dotall )

Tags: java, regex, jenkins

## Background

I am trying to use the `BUILD_LOG_REGEX` environment variable, which is provided by the emailext plugin, to filter a build log.  My regular expression is suppose to match everything between the "init:" and "Total time" strings.  My regular expression is as follows `init:(.*?)Total\stime`

The Jenkins emailext code is as follows

```
emailext( 
    body: "\${BUILD_LOG_REGEX, regex=\"init:(.*?)Total\\stime", maxMatches=10000000, showTruncatedLines=false, escapeHtml=true}",
    subject: 'Test Subject',
    mimeType: 'text/html',
    to: 'noname@gmail.com'
)
```

The build log is as follows

```
Started by user Chris Maggiulli
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on EC2 (sis-account) - java-build-11 (sir-2viyb9qh) in /home/ec2-user/workspace/z_test/email-build-log
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage (checkout)
Using the ‘stage’ step without a block argument is deprecated
Entering stage checkout
Proceeding
[Pipeline] checkout
Using sole credentials awsjobs/****** (awsjobs-AD-User) in realm ‘<https://svn.int.excelsior.edu:443> Private’
Updating https://svn.int.excelsior.edu/svn/sis_dev2 at revision '2021-08-10T13:18:37.454 +0000' --quiet
[Pipeline] stage (build)
Using the ‘stage’ step without a block argument is deprecated
Entering stage build
Proceeding
At revision 27558

[Pipeline] dir
Running in /home/ec2-user/workspace/z_test/email-build-log/sis
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ ant -Dsis.root=.. -Djava.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto.x86_64 -Djava.exec=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto.x86_64/bin/java make
Buildfile: /home/ec2-user/workspace/z_test/email-build-log/sis/build.xml

init:

compileSis:
     [copy] Copying 1 file to /home/ec2-user/workspace/z_test/email-build-log/sis/sis/WEB-INF/classes
     [copy] Copying 9 files to /home/ec2-user/workspace/z_test/email-build-log/sis/sis/WEB-INF/classes
    [javac] /home/ec2-user/workspace/z_test/email-build-log/sis/build.xml:108: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] Compiling 3372 source files to /home/ec2-user/workspace/z_test/email-build-log/sis/sis/WEB-INF/classes
    [javac] warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 7
    [javac] Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
    [javac] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    [javac] 1 warning

createSisWar:
   [delete] Deleting: /home/ec2-user/workspace/z_test/email-build-log/deploy/tomcat/sis.war
      [war] Building war: /home/ec2-user/workspace/z_test/email-build-log/deploy/tomcat/sis.war

FullSisBuild:

make:
     [echo] build complete.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 25 seconds
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // dir
[Pipeline] stage (email)
Using the ‘stage’ step without a block argument is deprecated
Entering stage email
Proceeding
[Pipeline] emailext
Sending email to: noname@gmail.com
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

While this works in almost all online regex testers it does not work in Jenkins.  I believe this is related to how the `BUILD_LOG_REGEX` macro implements [dotall](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-14000) but I can't get it to match across multiple lines.  I realize that `BUILD_LOG_REGEX` is implemented using `java.util.regex.Pattern`.  Can someone assist me with this?

## Attempts

I've also tried the following regex `init:(?s:.*)Total\stime` as well as attempting to use the BUILD_LOG_MULTILINE_REGEX ( with both regular expressions ) but both return no matches.

Comment: Sure the correct modifier is not `(?s:.*)`? [See](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-14000)

Comment: @g00se I've tried `init:(?s:.*)Total\stime` as well but it returns nothing.  I've also tried the same regex in my post but using BUILD_LOG_MULTILINE_REGEX but it also returns nothing

Comment: I don't know if it's just me, but i don't see an example of the init to total time strings/lines above…

Comment: Seen it, sorry.
*I've also tried the following regex init:(?s:.*)Total\stime*. More like `(?s:.*)init:(.*?)Total\stime`. That's a slightly queer way of implementing flags, but I'm assuming it's Jenkins-specific. If that doesn't work, it might be worth trying the normal `(?dm)init:(.*?)Total\stime`

Comment: @g00se unfortunately none of them work with either BUILD_LOG_REGEX or BUILD_LOG_MULTILINE_REGEX.  I did find a roundabout solution using BUILD_LOG_EXCERPT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution BUILD_LOG_EXCERPT

I found a roundabout solution using the BUILD_LOG_EXCERPT token.  The following code sample gives the results I am looking for using this token.

```
emailext(
   subject: "compile-check failed for $APP",
   body: "\${BUILD_LOG_EXCERPT, start=\"init:.*\", end=\"Total\\stime.*\"}",
   replyTo: '$DEFAULT_REPLYTO',
   mimeType: 'text/html',
   recipientProviders: [culprits()],
   to: 'noone@gmail.com'
)
```

The unescaped string is `${BUILD_LOG_EXCERPT, start="init:.*", end="Total\stime.*"}`

I am still interested in a solution using `BUILD_LOG_REGEX` or `BUILD_LOG_MULTILINE_REGEX`